# ORACLE - regular expressions

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a string column which need to extract the third word as string:

example:

```
select notes from prod.client;


1024 xyxyxyx 138 1025 eivneini 345 4. expected result=138
1028 swswsws 345 24090 bububu_ 1 2.   expected result=345
1028 acboru 345 1050 xwindiwf. 1 2.  expected result=345
1028 vnufenu 345 350 dnwufbuw 1 2.  expected result=345
1113 abudbu 138 1114 bububuw 12.5 1. expected result=138
```

the result should be a string value.

Any idea how to create a regular expression that pick this?

regards

Comment: Maybe I'm miscounting something, but the returned value seems to be the fourth word.

Comment: You are right, I already edited, it's the third one

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_substr()`.  For the third string:

```
select regexp_substr(notes, '[^ ]+', 1, 3)
from prod.client;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ccee8c740bb95e742e54fd0cfece679) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "word". Are all "words" in your strings separated by spaces, and everything that is not a space is part of a word?

For example: is `result=138` a single word, or is it two "words" separated by the equal sign?

If "words are separated by space, and everything that is not a space is part of a word", then Gordon Linoff's solution is correct.

But be aware of the possible problems. If that's your definition, then the string `Hello, world!` has two words: `Hello,` (including the comma!) and `world!` (including the exclamation point). Most applications don't use such a definition of word.

So, back to my first observation, at the top of this Reply. Define "word".

The convention, in regular expressions, is to define "word" as a maximal substring of consecutive characters that are either letters or digits or the underscore. That is represented by the escape sequence `\w` (in the POSIX standard and in Oracle regular expressions).

So, your answer should be something like

```
select regexp_substr(notes, '\w+', 1, 3)
from   ........
```

If your definition is different - for example if you must also allow hyphen and apostrophe - then you need to modify to something like

```
select regexp_substr(notes, '[[:alnum:]_''-]+', 1, 3)
from   ........
```

Notice the two apostrophes used to represent a single literal one, and remember that the hyphen must always appear first or last in a bracketed expression to stand for itself, otherwise it is a metacharacter.